# Raspberry server is unavailable for a while then its good again

Tags: raspbian, server

I have a server running in my home, it only runs deluged and a vpn server.
Sometimes it just becomes unavailable and i have no idea why. I log the temperature every 15 minutes and it is logging while i cant reach it, but it seems like it has no internet acces. Usually it takes a couple of hours, but it works after that. Now it went offline around 3pm and came back around 11 pm, but after a few minutes it went offline again. When its online the router can see it, but it cant see it while offline.
Restarting the router doesnt help.
Any idea what could be the problem or what should i check?

Comment: What is deluged?

Comment: wired or wireless? (if wireless, could be some interference issue) where is it logging the temperature, internally or externally? (if internally, then the fact that it logs the temperature means nothing) Fixed IP address or static (possible IP address duplication issue)

Comment: Check `/var/log/syslog` especially during the periods when the server is unavailable.

Comment: Deluged is a torrent app.
It is wired to my main router and logging the temp internally( i wanted to show with that info that its working since crontab is still logging, but it has no internet acces). I reserved the ip in the router to 192.168.1.76 and in crontab i have a script to send my public ip to a duckdns domain (My internet provider doesnt allow us to fix the ip).